# Last line in a `tcsh` script does not run

Tags: scripting, command-line-interface

I have a `tcsh` script that sets aliases during login. 
It seems like the last line in the file is not executed. If I put a new line after it - it works fine.

Example - bad:

```
...  
...  
...  
alias psu 'ps -fu ${LOGNAME}' <-- This does not run!!!
```

Example - good:

```
...  
...  
...  
alias psu 'ps -fu ${LOGNAME}' <-- This runs fine!!!
--> Empty line here
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because tcsh needs a CR character at the end of the line to execute the command, which is missing in your first example. Just end every line in a shell script with the enter key to be on the safe side.